# Kafka connect JDBC sink connector for Multi tenant app

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I plan to use kafka connect in multi-tenant app, how to change connection url in jdbc sink connector base on messages payload or topics name. so it can change database dynamically, or any advice to best implementation kafka connect in multi-tenant app

also is change connection url possible using SMT?

Answer (score 0):

The connection url cannot be changed based on records; the code starts one connection before writing any record.

You could use other frameworks for this like Flink, Spark, Apache NiFi, etc. where you could first groupBy a unique connection url, then write each batch of records with the same URL

Otherwise, you can use Kafka Streams to do the same. `flatMap` each record to a unique topic, for each database, then start `N` different JDBC sink connectors (maybe start an HTTP request to the Connect server each time you see a new URL)